# SQL SUM() of specified values in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains all the rounds for a game. Each round players gain ore lose score multiple times. I would like to `SUM()` the total score of the rounds I pass in the query per player.

*The score column is "sec_verdiend", and the rounds are "rondenaam"*
[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT IF(SUM(b.sec_verdiend) IS NULL, 0, SUM(b.sec_verdiend)) AS       tot_sec_verdiend 
    FROM abjmehlb_db.beurt b 
    WHERE b.spel_id = 511 AND b.rondenaam IN('369', 'opendeur', 'puzzle') AND      b.speler = 'Ger'
) as Ger, 
(
    SELECT IF(SUM(b.sec_verdiend) IS NULL, 0, SUM(b.sec_verdiend)) AS     tot_sec_verdiend 
    FROM abjmehlb_db.beurt b 
    WHERE b.spel_id = 511 AND b.rondenaam IN('369', 'opendeur', 'puzzle') AND   b.speler = 'Jasper'
) as Jasper
```

And this is the result:

[image]

So for example if I want the total score of the rounds "369", "finale" and "Ingelijst" the query sums only the score of those rounds together, and not the rest!

The output I require is the following using the example from above.

P1:(20 + 20 + 60 + -15 + -7 + -40 =)  38 | P2: (60 + 0 + 0 + -5 + -20 +-10 =)  25

**EDIT**

I've found the problem, the query goes wrong when you try to sum negative numbers. When I sum "speler = Ger", "369" and "opendeur" it returns 123. So something is going worng adding negative numbers.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: It would be better if you edit the question and show an example of the output you desire, because right now it looks like you're getting what you want.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: And if you fix the `WHERE` clause to use the correct values, you don't get those numbers? It was `spel_id = 501` but data is **`511`**. It's currently `rondenaam IN('369', 'opendeur', 'puzzle')` but you say you want `"369"`, **`"finale"`** and **`"Ingelijst"`**. It's currently `speler = 'Ger'`, but you list desired numbers for **`Bart`**.

Comment: Yes, you're right, forgot to update the result picture! Thanks.

Comment: So???? `Jasper` is 0 because you have no `Jasper` rows. `Ger` is `123` because `60 + 0 + 0 + 63 + 0` adds up to that. You are getting **exactly** what you asked for.

Comment: Nothing(!!) is going wrong adding negative numbers. There are no negative numbers matching your criteria. ***Hint:*** `puzzel != puzzle`

Comment: ***Hint 2:*** `opendeur != finale` and `Ingelijst != puzzle`. Also `Ingelijst != ingelijst`. In short, check your preconceptions, because you're way off the mark there.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the total score of the rounds "369", "finale" and "Ingelijst"
>   the query sums only the score of those rounds together

You meant to use `SUM()` with `CASE` statement like

```
sum(case when rondenaam IN('369','finale','Ingelijst') then 1 else 0 end) as Total
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `sum` of score per player per round then another option would be to use `GROUP BY` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT rondenaam, speler, sum(sec_verdiend)
FROM abjmehlb_db
WHERE speler = 'Bart' AND rondenaam = '369'
GROUP BY rondenaam, speler;
```